# Recreation of mdadm RAID backing store for drbd yields *The peer's disk size is too small!*

Tags: debian, mdadm, drbd

Some years ago, I've set up a storage cluster with stock Debian Linux using *mdadm* RAID  as backing store by using the Debian provided *drbd 0.8*. Currently there are two RAID6 volumes, comprised of some 2, and 14 TB disks.

Meanwhile, disks have been added to both nodes to provide more space, defective disks have been replaced, and upgrades to newer Debian releases have been applied.

Some background story for context: I experienced unusual high load and lots of KO timeouts on the active node *01* lately. Watching the output of `iostat -x 2` on *01*, I observed one disk to go up in *average queue size* numbers for brief periods, much more than each other. For fault isolation I manually set the secondary node *02* to be active and disconnected the drbd network connection volume by volume. With this I finally found the fault to be on one of two RAID volumes on the former primary node *01*.

I used `smartctl -t long` to run extended checks on the disks, and checked the output with `smartctl -a`. There were no obvious values hinting to imminent failure.

To rule out that particular disk, I recreated the volume as RAID5, leaving the suspicious disk out of the new volume. After creating new drbd metadata with default values (`drbdadm create-md resname`) and forcing the active node *02* to be sync source, I get the following message in *02*'s log:

`The peer's disk size is too small! (39066455672 < 39066476152 sectors)`

**The new volume is 20,480 sectors too small!**

Comparing values from `mdadm --detail`:

```
 Host | Array Size (blocks) | Used Dev Size (blocks)
------+----------------------------------------------
 01   |      19,533,834,240 |          1,953,382,400
 02   |      19,533,824,000 |          1,953,383,424
```

Next, I recreated the array again as RAID6, like it was before. Still, there's a size difference

Inspecting the arrays on both machines *01* (new array) and *02* (old array) with `mdadm --detail` and shoving them through diff shows:

```
--- 01  2023-01-19 13:37:48.552858896 +0100
+++ 02  2023-01-19 13:34:58.098143189 +0100
@@ -1,17 +1,17 @@
 /dev/md4:
            Version : 1.2
-     Creation Time : Thu Jan 19 13:37:11 2023
+     Creation Time : Fri Nov 26 11:23:33 2021
         Raid Level : raid6
-        Array Size : 19533824000 (18628.91 GiB 20002.64 GB)
-     Used Dev Size : 1953382400 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
+        Array Size : 19533834240 (18628.92 GiB 20002.65 GB)
+     Used Dev Size : 1953383424 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
       Raid Devices : 12
      Total Devices : 12
        Persistence : Superblock is persistent
 
      Intent Bitmap : Internal
 
-       Update Time : Thu Jan 19 13:37:24 2023
-             State : clean, resyncing 
+       Update Time : Thu Jan 19 13:34:11 2023
+             State : active 
     Active Devices : 12
    Working Devices : 12
     Failed Devices : 0
@@ -22,22 +22,20 @@
 
 Consistency Policy : bitmap
 
-     Resync Status : 0% complete
-
               Name : 4
-              UUID : 4a730173:b97ac886:8194cbed:f30861d2
-            Events : 3
+              UUID : d6e60c19:5b08166e:a6b78c2b:a2676f7d
+            Events : 4580
 
     Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
        0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
        1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
-       2       8       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
+       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
        3       8       32        3      active sync   /dev/sdc
-       4       8       48        4      active sync   /dev/sdd
-       5       8       80        5      active sync   /dev/sdf
-       6       8      144        6      active sync   /dev/sdj
-       7       8      240        7      active sync   /dev/sdp
-       8       8      128        8      active sync   /dev/sdi
-       9      65        0        9      active sync   /dev/sdq
-      10       8      176       10      active sync   /dev/sdl
+       4       8       80        4      active sync   /dev/sdf
+       5       8      128        5      active sync   /dev/sdi
+       6       8      112        6      active sync   /dev/sdh
+       7       8      144        7      active sync   /dev/sdj
+       8       8      160        8      active sync   /dev/sdk
+       9       8      176        9      active sync   /dev/sdl
+      10       8      192       10      active sync   /dev/sdm
       11       8      208       11      active sync   /dev/sdn
```

Forcing the *Used Dev Size* value from *02* yields:

```
mdadm: /dev/sda is smaller than given size. 1953382400K < 1953383424K + metadata
```

For multiple disk drives, not only for /dev/sda. How could this array have been functioning when *mdadm* now claims a lack of space per device?

**Questions:**

- Why is the new array using 1024 blocks less space per device?
- I have never used the *mdadm* option `-z max` on any occasion. Testing shows that even with `-z max` the *Used Dev Size* stays at 1953382400 blocks.
- Is there a way to force-create the array with whatever *mdadm* compatibility option to provide enough space to provide an equally sized backing store for *drbd* again?